# JAVA modifying XML file

Tags: java, exception, xml.modify

I'm trying to modify my Config.xml file from JAVA program, file contains data about MySql connection.

Here's the code after button click:

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        File f = new File("Config.xml");
        Document doc = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(f.getAbsolutePath());

        String url = server_field.getText();
        String user = db_login_field.getText();
        String pass = db_pass_field.getText();
        String baze = db_name_field.getText();

        klases.update_xml(doc, "jdbc/url", url);
        klases.update_xml(doc, "jdbc/username", user);
        klases.update_xml(doc, "jdbc/password", pass);
        klases.update_xml(doc, "jdbc/name", baze);

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer tf = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f)) {
             StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(fos);
             tf.transform(domSource, sr);
        }
```

update_xml function:

```
public static void update_xml(Document doc, String path, String def) {
    String p[] = path.split("/");
    //search nodes or create them if they do not exist
    Node n = doc;
    for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        NodeList kids = n.getChildNodes();
        Node nfound = null;
        for (int j = 0; j < kids.getLength(); j++) {
            if (kids.item(j).getNodeName().equals(p[i])) {
                nfound = kids.item(j);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (nfound == null) {
            nfound = doc.createElement(p[i]);  // LINE 300
            n.appendChild(nfound);
            n.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("\n")); //add whitespace, so the result looks nicer. Not really needed
        }
        n = nfound;
    }
    NodeList kids = n.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < kids.getLength(); i++) {
        if (kids.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            //text node exists
            kids.item(i).setNodeValue(def); //override
            return;
        }
    }

    n.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(def));

}
```

And here is XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jdbc>
    <url>localhost:3306</url>
    <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
    <username>username</username>
    <password>password</password>
    <name>database</name>
</jdbc>
```

And here's the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.w3c.dom.DOMException: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: An invalid or illegal XML character is specified. 
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.createElement(CoreDocumentImpl.java:622)
at programa.klases.update_xml(klases.java:300)
```

Line 300 commented.
Waiting for soliution, thank you!

Comment: A [space] character is been generted in your `p` array because of the leading `/` character in the path

Comment: Now I didn't get any error, but didn't get any changes in file too.

Comment: Your example code doesn't seem to save anything - but it works okay for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [space] character is been generted in your `p` array because of the leading `/` character in the path

You can remove the `/` from the original path...

```
update_xml(doc, "jdbc/url", url);
update_xml(doc, "jdbc/username", user);
update_xml(doc, "jdbc/password", pass);
update_xml(doc, "jdbc/name", baze);
```

which will get rid of the immediate error

> Now I didn't get any error, but didn't get any changes in file too.

None of you example code shows you actually saving the `Document` back to the file, once loaded, there is no association between the DOM and the source it come from, you need to save the contents yourself, for example...

```
DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f)) {
    StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(fos);
    tf.transform(domSource, sr);
}
```

Comment: Updated post, still nothing saves.

Comment: Use the save functionality AFTER you've finished updating the DOM (so under all the `update_xml` calles.  And it works fine for me